# Sending large files through socket android

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am trying to send large file about 2.3 GB through socket.
So,When i create byte array `new byte[fileLength]`,I will get the error that says out of memory.
my code is

```
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

        int fileLength = (int) file.length();

        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();

        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);

        mybytearray = new byte[fileLength];

        dis.readFully(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

        dos.writeUTF(file.getName());

        dos.writeLong(mybytearray.length);
        int i = 0;
        while (i<100) {
            dos.write(mybytearray, i*(mybytearray.length/100), mybytearray.length/100);
            final int c=i;
            Log.e("TAG", "REQ HANDLER: Completed: \"+c+\"%\"" );
            i++;

        }

        dos.flush();
```

How to can i send and receive this kind of large file through socket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you can't send the file at once as it's too large. You need to send it piece by piece like:

```
    File file = new File("someFile");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
    Socket socket;  //your socket
    OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);

    dos.writeUTF(file.getName());
    dos.writeLong(file.length());

    byte[] mybytearray = new byte[4096];
    int read = dis.read(mybytearray);
    while (read != -1) {
        dos.write(mybytearray, 0, read);
        read = dis.read(mybytearray);
    }
    dos.flush();
```

haven't run a test against the code above but you can get the idea.

Comment: There is no need to conditionally call different versions of `dos.write()` based on the return value of `dis.read()`. You can use this instead: `int read; while ((read = dis.read(mybytearray)) != -1) { dos.write(mybytearray, 0, read); }`

Comment: Anyone can explain how to receive that file in client.